# How to remove with jQuery tags using :not operator?

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible anyway to delete all `<p>` tags except that one who has an `<img>` tag inside nested, with jquery?

Here is my problem code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p>img:not").remove();
});
</script>

<p><img src="Anyimg.jpg"></p>
<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
<p>Who is your favourite</p>
```

It means the output should be just the image!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) selectors

```
$("p:not(:has(img))").remove();
```

```js
$("p:not(:has(img))").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><img src="Anyimg.jpg" alt="some image" /></p>
<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
<p>Who is your favourite</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this to to use the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method

```js
$("p").filter(function(){
    return $('img',this).length == 0;
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p><img src="Anyimg.jpg" alt="some image"></p>
<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
<p>Who is your favourite</p>
```